# can multiple threads can be implemented in every core in python

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am making an application in python where iam able to work with `multithreading` and `multiproceccing` but i need to connect a large sacle of devices. Is there any way to run multiple threads in each core.

Like if i have 4 cores then is there any way to run 2 threads in each core. So that we can have 8 concurrent threads running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@huhnmonster's answer is basically correct: you want the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) package, rather than the `multithreading` one.

This is actually fairly easy to do with the `Pool` construct:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

The number of processes you want to select depends on both the number of cores, the frequency of I/O requests for each process, and the number of threads of execution each core can support at once.

For example, most Intel Core i7 processors have 4 cores, but enough on-chip registers to store context for 2 processes and execute some operations in parallel. As a rule of thumb, you don't get twice the execution speed from this, but you often see 25-30% speedups. So if you were running your code on a Core i7, you'd want 8 running processes at a time. If your code blocks on I/O about half the time (you can use a profiler to estimate this), then a good guess at the correct number of processes would be 12-16. A little bit of experimentation would let you figure out the right number pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In Python there is no way to utilize multiple threads since it uses a so called GIL or Global Interpreter Lock, which means that only one thread can run Python code at a time.

Depending on your use-case threads still might suit your problem if it is IO-bound. Python uses cooperative multitasking, meaning threads give up control if they block, so if you for example need to ping multiple devices to see if they are still running, threads will speed up your program heavily.

If you need true concurrency, consider using multiprocessing, since it is process-based and spawns a new Python interpreter, therefor bypassing the GIL.

Comment: Even when working with `multiprocessing` can i handle 16-17 processess concurrently?

Comment: @Candy it really comes down to your workload, if you need to do some heavy number crunching you will only get speedups as long as the number of processes is lower or equal to your CPUs cores. If you only do IO based work, threads will probably work just as well. Added benefit is that you have stuff like shared memory with threads should you need that.